# How long does HP provide extended support for servers? Specifically a DL380 G5

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

We have 8 DL380 G5s in service as ESXi hosts.  The servers are currently under support until June of 2014.  How long does HP offer care packs after a product has been released?  I looked through all the documentation I could find but couldn't find anything saying something like HP will no longer support the DL380 G5 after a certain date in the future.

Comment: Why don't you call HP and ask them?

Comment: HP only publicly offers 1y extensions to warranties (you can re-up every year, and they still offer support for the DL380 line back to the G1 model on their site). Currently the DL380G5 1y NBD = $450 per server (for comparison the G1 costs $835 for the same). You can lookup any of this on [HP's Carepack Central](http://h20559.www2.hp.com/portal/site/cpc/)

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, HP will offer support for very long periods. It'll get insanely expensive the longer it gets, and anything past a certain point will be subject to a special contract between you and HP.

Like many vendors, they do structure their extended support costs so that buying new is attractive after a certain point, but if you really need *this DL380 G5 right here* for 10 years, they can probably accommodate you.

Comment: HP prices support based on their stock of spare parts. More parts -> lower prices. For most of their server the cost of 3y NBD extended warranty is very close to the cost of an equivalent new server with the standard 3y NBD warranty. I know HP will warranty some *very old* gear, but the prices get obscene quickly.